# Determine if activity is called from FCM notification or not

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM notifications for my app. A notification has no data. So, whenever the app is in the background, Main Activity is opened on the notification. There are 4 tabs on my Main Activity. I want to open Tab4 if the app is opened from notification otherwise Tab 2.

I want to check if the Main activity is opened from notification or not. As my notification has no data. I won't get anything in Intent extras.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `Extra` on `intent` to identify the source of the `Activity` launch

While calling from notifications do this

```
Intent notificationsIntent = new Intent(NotificationsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
notificationsIntent.putExtra("Source", "Notification");
startActivity(notificationsIntent);
```

In your `MainAcitivity` check like

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Source") == "Notification") {
    //set current tab to 4
} else {
    //set current tab to 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the app gets opened through a notification message (not a data message), the intent would contain a `source` value, which you can check to detect if the activity was opened using a notification.

```
 if (intent.hasExtra("source")) {
     // set tab to 4
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Notification message only (no Data message) you can check diferent values on intent received in activity: google.delivered_priority,
google.sent_time, google.ttl, google.original_priority, from, google.message_id, gcm.n.analytics_data, collapse_key

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    boolean bFromNotification = intent.hasExtra("google.delivered_priority");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boolean bFromNotification = getIntent().hasExtra("google.delivered_priority");
}
```